# Cleanning texts with Notepad++

Tags: java, regex, text, notepad++

I have a tweets document, it contains like that lines:

```
RichardJ0nes -- Should I upgrade to an iPhone 5? Decisions, decisions!
AnthonyMOliva -- @AnthonyMOliva AT&T offering iPhone 5 refurbished starting at $99: Two months after making its debut, refur... http://t.co/IsPDzIrD #BBC
mittrashi -- RT @timesofindia: Apple iPhone 5S, iPad 5 already in the works? - The Times of India http://t.co/s782BHp5
```

I want to clean this document. 
Firstly I want to clean the user names( example: RichardJ0nes --  or  @AnthonyMOliva ) and  secondly I want to clean links (example http://t.co/s782BHp5) .

It should be like that :

```
Should I upgrade to an iPhone 5? Decisions, decisions!
AT&T offering iPhone 5 refurbished starting at $99: Two months after making its debut, refur... 
Apple iPhone 5S, iPad 5 already in the works? - The Times of India
```

I try doing something with regular expression on the notepad++ but I could not clean the text

I try delete first usernames with
find `.*\(--\)` 
replace: `\1`

but it does not work on notepad++ . How should I do, please give me an idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for `(^\S+\s--|\bhttps?://\S+|(?:^|(?<=\s))[@#]\S+)\s?` and replace it with empty string.

Comment: Maybe add `(?:RT )?` before `[@#]` to match that also.

Comment: @garyh - I believe OP wants to keep that, even his/her question shows not. Otherwise the question is unclear about search/replace rules...

Comment: I agree, the OP is unclear as they don't explicitly state to remove `RT` but then it doesn't appear in the cleaned text. Just adding value!

Answer (score 2):

In notepad++ press `ctrl+f`, go to replace tab and at the bottom select **Regular Expression** in your **Search Mode** then perform the following operations

1. search for: `.* -- (.*)$` and replace all by `\1`
2. search for: `@[^ ]*`  and replace all by nothing (leave the replace input empty)
3. search for: `http[^ ]*` and replace all by nothing (leave the replace input empty)